# How to name an SD card

Tags: 14.04, sd-card

I have mounted an removable microSD card in Ubuntu 14.04. How can I give it a name (change the name from "SD Card" to something else)? The rename option is grayed-out.

Thank you.

Comment: Try using the `disks` utility or `gparted` if installed.

Comment: Is there anything on them? If not: format them. Then the option will be there to give it a label

Answer (score 2):

Command line method

```
sudo mlabel -i /dev/mmcblk0 ::{label}
```

where {label} is your name. Mind the device name: it probably will be mmcblk0 but it could have another name. See for instance `sudo fdisk -l` for the device name.

You might need to format it before you can label it (`init :: sector size (0) not a small power of two` is an error you might get indicating you need to format it).

Comment: gparted attempts to use mlabel, with no success on my system. Error messages are either `Total number of sectors (…) not a multiple of sectors per track (63)!` or `plain_io: Operation not permitted
buffer_flush: write: Operation not permitted`

Comment: there seems to be a catch 22 here... I am getting the same error as @scruss, but to suggest it needs to be formatted first, I have a card that I am using in a device and it seems to need to format the card itself or it won't recognize it.

Comment: I just added the suggested option "mtools_skip_check=1" to root's .mtoolsrc file, and it works perfectly